# Making Extent Report Appender Thread Safe

Tags: java, multithreading, extentreports

I am working on an Automation Framework and using Extent Report as a reporting tool. I am logging Android Logs and User Journeys using Slf4j logback.
I wanted to run my tests in parallel. What i want is to log Android logs and my user journeys with respect to my test. But because its not thread safe. So I am getting logs of one test in another. Here was my code for sequential tests:

**Listener Class**

```
ExtentTest test;
    ExtentReports extent=ExtentReporterNG.getReporterObject();
    AppiumDriver driver;
    
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        test=extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        ExtentReportsAppender.setExtentTest(test);
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        ExtentReportsAppender extentAppender = new ExtentReportsAppender();
        extentAppender.setName("ExtentReportsAppender");
        extentAppender.start();  // Start the appender
        rootLogger.addAppender(extentAppender);
        try {
            driver=(AppiumDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getField("driver")
                    .get(result.getInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ((CanRecordScreen) driver).startRecordingScreen();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
        
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Test Passed");
        ((CanRecordScreen) driver).stopRecordingScreen();
        cleanupLogger();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
        try {
            stopRecording(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        cleanupLogger();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        test.skip(result.getThrowable());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }
    
    private void cleanupLogger() {
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        ExtentReportsAppender extentAppender = (ExtentReportsAppender) rootLogger.getAppender("ExtentReportsAppender");
        if (extentAppender != null) {
            rootLogger.detachAppender(extentAppender);  // Detach the appender
            extentAppender.stop();  // Stop the appender
        }
    }   
    
    public void stopRecording(String methodName) throws IOException {

           String media = ((CanRecordScreen) driver).stopRecordingScreen();
           String dirPath =   System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"videos";
           File videoDir = new File(dirPath);
           FileOutputStream stream = null;
           
        try {
          stream = new FileOutputStream(videoDir + File.separator +methodName+".mp4");
                stream.write(Base64.decodeBase64(media));
                stream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                if(stream != null) {
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

**ExtentReportsAppender Class**

```
public class ExtentReportsAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>{ 
    private static ExtentTest test;

    public static void setExtentTest(ExtentTest testInstance) {
        test = testInstance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        if (test != null) {
            switch (event.getLevel().levelInt) {
                case Level.INFO_INT:
                    test.log(Status.INFO, event.getFormattedMessage());
                    break;
                case Level.WARN_INT:
                    test.log(Status.WARNING, event.getFormattedMessage());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's What I tried:
I created a thread Local variable for Extent Test and my Appium Driver that i get from reflection. By this, the test in extent report and the video recording became Thread Safe but the Logs did not.

**Listener Class**

```
public class Listeners extends AppiumUtils implements ITestListener,IConfigurationListener{
    ExtentReports extent=ExtentReporterNG.getReporterObject();
    AppiumDriver driver;
    private ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driverThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> testThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private ThreadLocal<ExtentReportsAppender> appenderThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentTest test=extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        testThreadLocal.set(test);
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        ExtentReportsAppender extentAppender = new ExtentReportsAppender(testThreadLocal.get());
        appenderThreadLocal.set(extentAppender);
        extentAppender.setName("ExtentReportsAppender");
        extentAppender.start();  // Start the appender
        rootLogger.addAppender(extentAppender);
        try {
            driver = (AppiumDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getField("driver")
                    .get(result.getInstance());
            driverThreadLocal.set(driver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ((CanRecordScreen) driver).startRecordingScreen();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
     }
        
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        testThreadLocal.get().log(Status.PASS, "Test Passed");
        try {
            driver=driverThreadLocal.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((CanRecordScreen) driver).stopRecordingScreen();
        cleanupLogger();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        testThreadLocal.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        try {
            driver=driverThreadLocal.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
        stopRecording(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            
        }

        /*try {
            driver=(AppiumDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getField("driver")
                    .get(result.getInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            try {
                
                test.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(getScreenshotAsBase64(driver),"Screenshot");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
          cleanupLogger();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        testThreadLocal.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }
    
    private void cleanupLogger() {
        Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
//      ExtentReportsAppender extentAppender = (ExtentReportsAppender) rootLogger.getAppender("ExtentReportsAppender");
        ExtentReportsAppender extentAppender=appenderThreadLocal.get();
        if (extentAppender != null) {
            rootLogger.detachAppender(extentAppender);  // Detach the appender
            extentAppender.stop();  // Stop the appender
        }
    }   
    
    public void stopRecording(String methodName) throws IOException {
           AppiumDriver driver = driverThreadLocal.get();
           String media = ((CanRecordScreen) driver).stopRecordingScreen();
           String dirPath =   System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"videos";
           File videoDir = new File(dirPath);
           FileOutputStream stream = null;
           
        try {
          stream = new FileOutputStream(videoDir + File.separator +methodName+".mp4");
                stream.write(Base64.decodeBase64(media));
                stream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                if(stream != null) {
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

**ExtentReportsAppender Class**

```
public class ExtentReportsAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>{ 
    private ExtentTest test;

    public ExtentReportsAppender(ExtentTest testInstance) {
        test = testInstance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        if (test != null) {
            switch (event.getLevel().levelInt) {
                case Level.INFO_INT:
                    test.log(Status.INFO, event.getFormattedMessage());
                    break;
                case Level.WARN_INT:
                    test.log(Status.WARNING, event.getFormattedMessage());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected that

- By setting the thread safe testInstance instead of a static test will print relevant test logs.
- By Setting the AppenderThreadLocal on Test Start and by Getting it in Clean up logger will clean that test's logs